# How to position div at bottom of it container

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a graphs that bars are at bottom and i don't want to fix position in horizontal. because bar has various width.

I want like this http://jsfiddle.net/y2c8t/ but let the bars at bottom.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="bar" style="height: 80px; background-color: #090;"></div>
   <div class="bar" style="height: 60px; background-color: #060;"></div>
   <div class="bar" style="height: 40px; background-color: #030;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #CCC; 
    position: relative;    
}
.bar {
    width: 40px; 
    background-color: #060; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

This is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/53uHp/

Answer (score 2):

I may as well chime in.  remove the `float:left` and add `display:inline-block;`

```
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #CCC;    
}
.bar {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 40px; 
    background-color: #060; 
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
}
```

[**jSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/y2c8t/1/)

Comment: It will work only when the wrapper will have 100px and first bar 80px (because of `top: 20px`). It's just for this situation, not in general.

Comment: the OP didn't ask for something that works for every possible situation.  In this case his wrapper has a fixed height, so this works. But thank you for your clarification -1

Answer (score 1):

You have to avoid inline style as much as possible. Here my suggest:

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bar" id="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar" id="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar" id="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #CCC; 
    position: relative;    
}
.bar {
    width: 40px; 
    background-color: #060; 
    bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
}

#bar1{
  height: 80px; background-color: #090;position:absolute;  
}
#bar2{
  height: 60px; background-color: #060;position:absolute;left:40px;
}
#bar3{
   height: 40px; background-color: #030;position:absolute;left:80px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53uHp/4/)

Comment: I had already done this, but i don't want to use "left: 40px" and "left: 80px". Can it float them automatically when next bar become by difference width?

Answer (score 0):

you could add the following styling to container element:

```
transform: rotateX(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the relative positioning and adding `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: bottom` to `.bar` as well as adding `line-height: 100px` to `.container`. To make sure the bars stay at the bottom even if you adjust the container height, make sure you adjust the line-height value to correspond to the new height.

http://jsfiddle.net/JF4sB/

```
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: #CCC; 
}
.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 40px; 
    background-color: #060; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also believe absolute positioning can be the answer, however, the other answers here all have to do special cases for each new bar you have to make. So instead, why not wrap the bar into just a content holder, float them, and have them positioned inside those.

I based it off your example...because I was feeling lazy, but here is what is going on

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="bar" style="height: 80px; background-color: #090;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="bar" style="height: 60px; background-color: #060;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="bar" style="height: 40px; background-color: #030;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Wrapping each bar with a bar-container so we can both float them and position them at the bottom at the same time.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #CCC;   
}
.bar-container {
    width: 40px; 
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
}
.bar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The bar-containers are floated, so you can have as many bars as you want, the height is set to the same as the container, otherwise they appear as if not having content (the absolute positioned inner content has no impact on it) and have position relative so we can place the bars themselves at the bottom. And the bars now have position absolute, so they are now placed relative to the parent div (because that has a position of other than static) and bottom: 0 specifies that they should be at the bottom. The width property lets them keep the width.

Here is how it looks in JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y2c8t/4/

This way you can just keep adding stuff with no need for special cases for each.